# show that an open interval is not an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I would like to know how to show that an open interval such as $(a,b)$ is not an open subset of complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Take $x\in(a,b)$. You want to show that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $|x-z|<\epsilon$ but $z\notin(a,b)$. Can you continue?

Comment: Keep in mind the topology of the complex plane, where we have open disks as basic open neighborhoods.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x \in (a,b)$. For every $\varepsilon > 0$, $y = x+i\varepsilon/2 \notin (a,b)$ and the distance between $y$ and $x$ is less then $\varepsilon$. In other words, no open disc centered at $x$ lies completely in $(a,b)$, which means that the interval can't be open.